# Como conseguir a localização do GPS de quem acessar o website?

Tags: javascript, html5, gps, google-maps-api-3, geolocalização

Olá
Preciso desenvolver um website que cria rotas, estou utilizando a Google API's JavaScript. Preciso conseguir a localização do usuário, porem a mesma deve ser do GPS caso o usuário esteja acessando através de um dispositivo mobile,  e não por IP como a função do HTML5.

É possível acessar os dados do GPS através de uma aplicação web? Como desenvolvo isso?

Answer (score 4):

Você não consegue acessar as configurações de hardware de um dispositivo pelo navegador. O máximo que você pode fazer é utilizar o [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp), mediante a aceitação do usuário, para obter as coordenadas de localização do usuário.

Como pode ser visto [na documentação da mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Using_geolocation), o **geolocation** não é baseado, isoladamente, no IP. Se o dispositivo possuir um GPS, ele irá utilizar o GPS para calcular a localização, o que pode ocasionar uma demora maior para obter os dados.

Abaixo está um exemplo de como utilizar a Geolocation, retirado da [w3School.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error)

```html
<html><head></head><body contenteditable="false">

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>



</body></html>
```

Agora, se realmente deseja utilizar o GPS do dispositivo, você precisará desenvolver um aplicativo e solicitar a permissão do usuário antes. Essa permissão é definida no APP.

> Para ver o funcionamento acesse o site do exemplo, pois existem bloqueios de conexões seguras (HTTPS).

Comment: Mas com o HTML5 a localização será através do IP. o que não poderá ser utilizado nesta aplicação, pois ocorre um erro de localização relativamente grande. Além disso o google chrome não está nem exibindo a mensagem para permitir compartilhar a localização. Mesmo assim agradeço.

Comment: @EliardoMarini O problema é que você não tem como fazer o que deseja sem desenvolver um app para essa finalidade. Outra, o Chrome (à partir da versão 50) aceita a utilização [mediante endereços confiáveis](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only), ou seja, endereços com HTTPS e não HTTP.